# Is there a way to detect collision through optical flow of a moving object?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am working on a project to detect accidents on a road using Python. I have detected vehicles using background subtraction and applied calcOpticalFlowFarneback (OpenCV) to find optical flow, which gives me motion vectors of those vehicles. What I want to know is, how to detect collision through the calculated optical flow? I am stuck at this point and Google didn't help me. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Can you be more specific? [ask]

Comment: Since you have locations of vehicles isn't this just a simple case of search for overlapping or touching boundaries? Isolate the vehicles (get a rectangle around them) and check for any "contact" if possible. PS: I dont use OpenCV (so don't ask for code).

Comment: Some examples would be great. Otherwise, isn't it just as simple as finding intersections of the optical flows?